# Why am I getting the error no such file or directory?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import shutil

csv_files = []
for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        csv_files.append(file)

dataset_dir = 'datasets3'

try:
    mkdir = 'mkdir {0}'.format(dataset_dir) #batch command
    os.system(mkdir)
except:
    pass 

for csv in csv_files:
    mv_file = "mv '{0}' {1}".format(csv, dataset_dir) #batch command
    os.system(mv_file)

data_path = os.getcwd()+ '/'+ dataset_dir +'/'

for file in csv_files:
    belton[file] = pd.read_csv(path+file)
```

I am getting this error (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'MMJK\Desktop\ExcelVGRevenueReport.csv') after running the final bit of code.

Where am I going run?

Comment: In the last line, where are you defining "path"?

Comment: Try using https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html and path to manipulate files and file paths

Comment: because the file or directory does not exist. what happens when you type `ls MMJK\Desktop\ExcelVGRevenueReport.csv` in the terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

You have moved your csv file(s) into the datasets3 folder. You need to load rthem from there.

Your last line should be

```py
    belton[file] = pd.read_csv(data_path+file)
```